# What is wrong with my JavaScript append function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

In the below method, an object `o` is appended to a list of objects `qs`. The commented part does not work, the now uncommented part does work. What is wrong with the commented part?

```
onCreate(o) {

    // This works (using lodash)
    this.setState({ qs: _.concat(this.state.qs, { id: this.getNextID(), ...o }) });

    // Is this not the same like the above?
    // let newQuestionnaire = {id: this.getNextID(), title: o.title, description: o.description};
    // let questionnaires = this.state.qs.push(newQuestionnaire);
    // this.setState({
    //     qs: questionnaires,
    // });
}
```

---

Edit: Maybe it helps somebody: the first thing coming up on Google is `push`:
[image]

--> Dont do that.

Comment: Don't use `.push()` to modify state. It is not pure. State should only be modified through pure operations. On top of that, `.push()` returns the _length_ of the modified array, not the array. If you want to do this without lodash, you can do `let questionnaires = this.state.qs.concat(newQuestionnaire);`

Comment: I don't know lodash, but it is a crime to modify state like you did it (via push).
You should firstly copy the state like (here i shallow copy it): let questionnaires = [...this.state.qs]; and then questionnaires.push(newQuestionnaire);
And at the end this.setState...

Answer (score 3):

[Array Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) return

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called

try this

```
let newQuestionnaire = {id: this.getNextID(), title: o.title, description: o.description};
this.setState({qs: [...this.state.qs, thisquestionnaires]})
```